# Explain the lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a method that contains a `lambda` expression:

```
public int noOfComplementaryPairs1(int arr[], int k) {

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        map.merge(k - arr[i], 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    return Arrays.stream(arr).map(element -> map.getOrDefault(element, 0)).sum();
}
```

Can someone explain to me what the last 2 lines mean?  I am not new to Java, but sometimes I get confused with some expressions like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map.merge...` : the first param is the key in the map, the second param is the value in the map when this key is not present, the third one is a `BiFunction` that tells u how to merge two keys,  since u cant have two keys with the same value inside a Map..

The last line is pretty simple too: you are streaming the array, mapping each element of that array with: `map.getOrDefault(element, 0)`, which means get the value from the `map` with `key = element` or the default of zero if it is not present; then `sum` them all.

Comment: How about the lambda expression? It will be helpful to upvote the question btw

Comment: How about using `Map<Integer, Integer> map =
                IntStream.range(0, arr.length).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> k - arr[i], i -> 1, Integer::sum));` instead of the `for` loop? Any pros or cons you might want to add to the answer.

Comment: @nullpointer hardly do I agree here, way less readable; but ultimately it's the OP to decide